# how can Angular http post function return a boolean type?

Tags: angular, post

I am trying to call a API to return boolean response, but it doesn't work. 
This below is my code.

product.component.ts

```
addToCart() {
    let item = {
      Title: this.product.name,
      UserId: parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("id")),
      Num: parseInt(this.count.toString()),
      Img: this.product.imgs[0],
      Price: this.product.price
    }
    let existed;
    this.cartService.checkExisted(item).subscribe(res => existed = res);
    //existed is always undefined, but what expected is true or false;
    console.log("response:" + existed)  
    }
}
```

cart.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  checkExisted(item) {
    return this.http.post("/api/Cart/CheckCartItem", item).map(res => 
res.text());
  }
}
```

And I used PostMan to test this post request, it does work with true or false response body.

Comment: You can't think async function to work in sync manner, `existed` value will be only available after `subscribe` function  gets called. So consider putting console inside `subscribe` function

Comment: This is standard mistake people make related to `async` calls... When you _subscribe_ so something it **doesn't** get executed immediately (it's asynchronous), so you need to `console.log` it inside subscribe block.

Comment: But what if I need the existed value to deal with the next code logic? For example, if existed is true,do sth, else do sth.

Comment: Then put result in block and do something in that block... Check the answer below if you don't know how to create a block inside _subscribe_ method...

Comment: Thank you so much gays, it works. Maybe I need more time to figure out the observables in Angular!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkExisted() retuned `Observable` and `subscribe` returns subscription. Calling `Subscribe` is an asynchronous method.

Below is the correct way of getting the required value.

```
this.cartService.checkExisted(item).subscribe(res => {
        console.log("response:" + existed) 
        existed = res;
    });


addToCart() {
    let item = {
      Title: this.product.name,
      UserId: parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("id")),
      Num: parseInt(this.count.toString()),
      Img: this.product.imgs[0],
      Price: this.product.price
    }
    let existed;
    this.cartService.checkExisted(item).subscribe(res => {
        console.log("response:" + existed) 
        existed = res;
    });
    //existed is always undefined, but what expected is true or false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But if we put "console.log("response:" + existed)" before "existed = res". The result would still be undefined or not?

Comment: @HanwenGuo existed will be undefined at that time as the value is not being assigned to existed